# isdigit() returning true for integers 10 and up

Tags: c

Novice C student here.

Could someone please explain why isdigit() is returning true for values 10+?
I'm doing a pretty basic assignment regarding a guessing game and must use isdigit() to inform user if he has entered a number 1-10 or not.
The program seems to be running fine otherwise, I just would like to know the reasoning behind isdigit() returning true for values 10+.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <time.h>

int main()
{
 int iRandomNum = 0;
 char cResponse = '0';

 srand(time(NULL));
 iRandomNum = (rand() % 10) + 1;

 printf("\nGuess a number between 1 and 10: ");
 scanf("%c", &cResponse);

 if (!isdigit(cResponse) || cResponse<'0'+1)
    printf("\nYou did not enter a number 1-10");

 else if ((cResponse - '0') == iRandomNum)
    printf("\nCorrect!");

 else
 {
    printf("\nSorry, you guessed wrong\n");
    printf("The correct guess was %d\n", iRandomNum);
 }
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Only the first letter(digit) is (input)evaluated.

Comment: `10` is not a digit! And `cResponse<'0'+1` -> `cResponse<'1'`. But that does not mean what you nedd either.

Answer (score 4):

If you add a `printf` to log the value of `cResponse`, the problem will become apparent very quickly:

```
printf("\nGuess a number between 1 and 10: ");
scanf("%c", &cResponse);

printf("cResponse is %c\n", cResponse);
```

outputs:

```
Guess a number between 1 and 10: 10
cResponse is 1
```

As you can see, only the first character is stored in `cResponse` (which makes sense, as it's just a single character), and since that first character is a digit, your `isdigit()` call returns true.

If you want to read numbers greater than 10, you can read to an `int` instead:

```
int cResponse = 0;

printf("\nGuess a number between 1 and 10: ");
scanf("%d", &cResponse);

printf("cResponse is %d\n", cResponse); // prints '10' if I type '10'
```

Note that you cannot use `isdigit()` in this case, although you can still easily check your bounds using `if (cResponse >= 0 && cResponse <= 10)`.

Answer (score 0):

You are passing a `char` to `isdigit`, which can only hold a single character.  Thus, while you may be typing in `10`, only the first character (which is a digit) is getting into `cResponse`.

Comment: I was thinking that it would return a false if I entered a value with double characters. This is very useful to know that isdigit does not consider anything beyond the first character in this case.

Comment: It's not `isdigit`. As you can see from the log in my answer, `cResponse` itself only contains one character, because you asked `scanf` to only read one character.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of reading the users input as a char, read it in as an int. This way you can just use `if(guess >= 1 && guess <= 10)`. Since you need 10 as part of the range of inputs a char (which is a single character) wont do. You will either need to use a string (which will make things more complicated) or just use an int.